# Cordova Push Notification always giving invalid notification

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

In my phonegap for WP8 application , i need to achieve toast notification using cordova push plugin. Everything is ok except i am always getting same toast notification as follows.

```
{\"hash\":\"\",\"html\":-1,\"url\":null,\"content\":\"\",\"userdata\":\"\",\"onStart\":false
```

What is the reason for this? Please help me.

Comment: Too few information to diagnose.

Comment: i got the push token form MPNS. But always getting the same ToastPush in OnPushAccepted callback.

Comment: You should show your codes.